# On the electrodynamics of moving bodies

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

> For if the
>   magnet is in motion and the conductor at rest, there arises in the neighbourhood of the magnet an electric field with a certain definite energy, producing a current at the places where parts of the conductor are situated. But if the
>   magnet is stationary and the conductor in motion, no electric field arises in the
>   neighbourhood of the magnet. In the conductor, however, we find an electro motive force, to which in itself there is no corresponding energy, but which gives
>   rise—assuming equality of relative motion in the two cases discussed—to electric currents of the same path and intensity as those produced by the electric
>   forces in the former case.

In the above paragraph what did Einstein meant by "however, we find an electro motive force, to which in itself there is no corresponding energy" and till end?

Source : [On electrodynamics of moving bodies](http://sites.ifi.unicamp.br/aguiar/teach/f-589/notas-de-aulas/on-the-electrodynamics-of-moving-bodies/)

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to electromagnetic induction. In the first case, the magnet is moving relative to the observer's frame, so an electric field is measured. For the second case, the magnet is not moving relative to the observer, but the conductor is. Therefore, in the conductor's frame of reference there is an electric field, providing the said electromotive "force."

Mathematically, if for some reference frame a magnetic field is changing, the electric field satisfies $\nabla\times \mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you know the difference between how the emf induced in the two cases.
It meant that the emf  generated suppose it to be a battery but the battery can't sustain itself . It has no energy of itself at any instant. As long as you provide the mechanical energy p.d will be maintained.